# Computing uniformizer in linearly disjoint totally ramified extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite totally ramified extension of a local field $K$. Let $E$ and $E'$ be subextensions in $L/K$, linearly disjoint over $K$ with $E E'=L$.

Is there a method to compute a uniformizer $\pi_L$ in $L$ with the two uniformizers $\pi_E$ and $\pi_{E'}$?

In general there exists a polynomial $g \in K(\pi_{E'})[X]$ satisfying $\pi_L = g(\pi_E)$. Is it possible to get a more specific relation between $\pi_L$, $\pi_E$ and $\pi_{E'}$?
I tried to work by defining $\pi_E:= N_{L/E}(\pi_L)$ and $\pi_{E'}$ resp., but it lead nowhere.

Comment: Depends on the ramification degrees. If $e(L/E)$ and $e(L/E')$ are coprime, you can use Bezout's identity and use $\pi_E^a\pi_{E'}^b$ for suitable integers $a,b$. Otherwise you need something more complicated. For example with $K=\Bbb{Q}_2$, $E=K(\sqrt{2})$, $E'=K(i)$, $\pi_E=\sqrt2$, $\pi_{E'}=1+i$, we quickly see that $(1+i)-\sqrt2$ generates the third power of the prime ideal, so dividing that by either $1+i$ or $\sqrt2$ gives a uniformizer. I mildly prefer division by $\sqrt2$ for then we get $1-\zeta_8$, familiar from global cyclotomic fields.